# how to get dump of column in mysql>

Tags: mysql, dump

I want to have dump of column like var_dump in php.

For eg:

> select dump(col_name)  from table_name
>
> o/p =>
>
> Typ=96 Len=10: 113,119,101,114,116,121,32,32,32,32

but it says such function does not exists. which function in,mysql does that or how to go for it

Comment: I want this o/p: which is a dump as var_dump in php which gives you the type, length,ascii value of data => Typ=96 Len=10: 113,119,101,114,116,121,32,32,32,32

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get list of values separated by comma:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(col_name SEPARATOR ',') ...
```

Note. The result of `GROUP_CONCAT` depends on `max_allowed_packet` and `group_concat_max_len` variables; if you have many records in your table, you need to increase default values (`SET group_concat_max_len = xxxx`);